# How to edit Cocos2d 3.x sprite builder ccb file?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I need to know how to open a ccb file in Sprite Builder for Cocos2d 3.x

This is attached a screenshot for my file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gW8z.png

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about this filetype and application, but have you tried simply dragging it in or something? Searching this website for the word "CCB" gives a lot of stuff: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/369/build-your-own-flappy-bird-with-spritebuilder-and , have you read it? (ctrl/cmd+F -> 'ccb', fourth result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open the complete project in SpriteBuilder, you cannot open single *.ccb* files.
The root folder of your project needs to be called *PROJECTNAME.spritebuilder* and you need to open that in SpriteBuilder to edit a *.ccb* file that is contained in a project:

[image: SpriteBuilder file structure]